# How can I close a popup window when the URL changes?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function that opens a popup window when a user clicks on a given link. Below is the function:

```
function openPopup() {
    let params = `scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=1600,height=900,left=0,top=0`;
    open('/form', 'Tracking', params);
};
```

When the popup opens up, I'd like to close the window after the URL changes in the popup window -- is this possible?

I've tried to add `hashchange`( [MDN Window hashchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event)) event from within the opened popup it doesn't seem to be working at all.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Barmar

I've modified it so that popup window closes on the 2nd `unload` event and it worked like a charm.

```
function openPopup() {
    let sum = 0
    let params = `scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=1600,height=900,left=0,top=0`;
    let win = open('/form', 'Tracking', params);
    win.addEventListener('unload',() => {
        sum += 1;
        if (sum > 1) win.close();
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Only the script that opened the window can close it, so the window can't close itself.

The script that opened the window may be able to listen for events on the window. The `unload` event is the one that's triggered when the URL changes (`hashchange` will be triggered just from changing the hash in the same page).

```js
function openPopup() {
    let params = `scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=1600,height=900,left=0,top=0`;
    let win = open('/form', 'Tracking', params);
    win.addEventListener("unload", function() {
      win.close();
    });
};
```

Comment: I've tried that but when I click on the link the popup displays for half a second and then closes

Comment: I experienced the same as @EverythingDigital. Tried in chrome and ff

Comment: I guess internally it works as an empty document redirecting to `/form`, and it treats that as an unload event.

Comment: @Barmar I tried wrapping it in `win.addEventListener('load', function() { win.addEventListener('unload', //...` that prevented it from closing immediately, but didnt close it when the url changed

Comment: @Barmar to test, I've added `win.addEventListener('unload',() => {console.log('fired')})`, what's interesting is that it fires off twice: once when the page has loaded and again when the URL changes. If I navigate to more URLs after that it does not continue to fire off

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a `window.close()` to an event listener for `window.onload` and `window.onbeforeunload` and it didn't work. The only thing that worked was hooking into the click event of anchor tags, this might work for you:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a')).forEach( a => {
    a.onclick = () => window.close();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that's possible. Better to use jquery ajax call to trigger the page and execute whatever is in it, if that's what you were trying to accomplish by popping up the window